# Partially Applied Function - Parentheses around 2nd Arg

Tags: haskell

I implemented an exercise from [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions).

```
isUpperCase' :: Char -> Bool
isUpperCase' = (`elem` ['A'..'Z'])
```

As I understand, `(elem ['A'..'Z'])` is a partially applied function. Calling `isUpperCase' 'B'` results in calling `isUpperCase apply 'B'`, which results in `True`.

Note that, without the parentheses, the following compile-time error occurs:

```
*Main> :l IsUpperCase.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( IsUpperCase.hs, interpreted )

IsUpperCase.hs:3:16: parse error on input ``'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What's the reason for surrounding the partially applied function with parentheses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the fact that the function is surrounded by ``'s.

In haskell `` foo `bar` baz `` is exactly the same as `bar foo baz`. It converts prefix function application into an infix operator.

Just like other operators we can use sectioning like `(2 *)`. In this case

```
(`elem` ['A'..'Z'])
\a -> a `elem` ['A'..'Z']
\a -> elem a ['A' .. 'Z']
flip elem ['A' .. 'Z']
```

This is just a clever (hacky) way to avoid writing `flip`. What you have is equivalent to

```
isUpperCase' = flip elem ['A' .. 'Z']
```

Comment: so this function definition: `('elem' ['A'..'Z'])` returns a partially applied function that expects an argument in front of `elem`...? What's the issue when removing the parentheses then? [sorry if you already listed why. I just didn't understand]

Comment: @KevinMeredith They're backticks, you need the parenthesis to form an operator section, like `(*2)`, `(10%)`, `(False ||)`.